# In Spider-Man No Way Home, how did *anti-hero* come into this universe?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-no-way-home, venom-let-there-be-carnage

First, this is not a copy of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/258354/why-was-electro-summoned-by-dr-stranges-spell).

Okay, so in the movie, we know that the spell was miscast and actually brought all the people from other worlds who already know that Peter Parker is Spider-Man. The question of Electro is one thing, at least Electro is aware of Spider-Man. The bigger question is how did Venom/Eddie Brock get sucked into that universe?

At the end credits of *Venom: Let There Be Carnage*, he's transported into Spider-Man's universe by some means. It's not because of anything Venom does - which was made explicit in the after-credits scene. Presumably, it's through Dr. Strange's spell. Also made clear is that Venom does not know who Spider-Man is in NWH. Further, he was, presumably, shot back into his own universe (with a little bit of Venom-goo left behind) at the end of NWH.

So why was Venom brought in by Dr. Strange's spell?

Comment: How is it "made clear [...] that Venom does not know who Spider-Man is in NWH"?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: [Why is this character transported into the MCU?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/258446/why-is-this-character-transported-into-the-mcu)

Comment: Venom actually knows who the spider man was.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Warning: this answer contains spoilers for both *Venom: Let There Be Carnage* and *Spider-Man: No Way Home*.**

Eddie's initial transference to the MCU seemingly occurred in the mid-credits scene of *Venom: Let There Be Carnage*.

Eddie is lying on a bed watching a soap opera on television, when the symbiote mentions that it has a past that Eddie doesn't know about, including "80 billion light-years of hive knowledge across universes".

It decides to give Eddie a taste of this knowledge, and just as that happens, there's a distortion effect around the room, and Eddie suddenly finds himself lying on a bed in a different room, where J. Jonah Jameson is on TV, reporting on the reveal of Spider-Man's secret identity.

Eddie then assumes his Venom form, walks over to the TV screen -- which is showing a close-up of an unmasked Spider-Man's (Tom Holland's) face -- and the symbiote says "That guy..." and licks the screen, possibly signifying some degree of recognition.

> SYMBIOTE: Oh, I love this show.
>
> EDDIE BROCK: Yeah.
>
> SYMBIOTE: Maximiliano’s feelings are not being validated.
>
> EDDIE BROCK: Yeah, well, he never should’ve kept such an insane secret, man.
>
> SYMBIOTE: **We all have a past, Eddie.**
>
> EDDIE BROCK: What, are you… you hiding stuff from me?
>
> SYMBIOTE: **80 billion light-years of hive knowledge across universes would explode your tiny little brain.**
>
> EDDIE BROCK: What-what does that even mean, man?
>
> SYMBIOTE: **Well, let me give you a taste, then. Just the smallest fraction of the things we symbiotes have experienced.**
>
> EDDIE BROCK: Okay.
>
> SYMBIOTE: Ready, Eddie?
>
> EDDIE BROCK: Yeah.
>
> SYMBIOTE: Whoa. What’s happening?
>
> EDDIE BROCK: No, no, no, no. No, no, no, no, no.
>
> SYMBIOTE: What the hell is that?!
>
> EDDIE BROCK: Oh, that’s a… that-that’s just a towel. Where are we? Wh-What did you do?
>
> SYMBIOTE: It wasn’t me.
>
> J. JONAH JAMESON [on television]: Incredibly, this shocking revelation brought to life by yours truly has only raised…
>
> EDDIE BROCK: What? What-what... what is this?
>
> J. JONAH JAMESON [on television]: …of Peter Parker, aka Spider-Man, aka the Spider Menace. But rest assured, dear viewers, we here at The Daily Bugle will...
>
> SYMBIOTE: **That guy...**
>
> <sub>*Venom: Let There Be Carnage* (2021)</sub>

The implication of all this seems to be that the symbiote -- through a hive mind link with symbiotes in other universes -- had knowledge of the Peter Parker/Spider-Man of another universe, and that when it shared this knowledge with Eddie, both of them unwittingly became subject to the spell cast by Dr. Strange in *Spider-Man: No Way Home*.

---

Variety recently published an interview with *Spider-Man: No Way Home* screenwriters, Erik Sommers and Chris McKenna, and McKenna confirmed that the symbiote was aware of the connection between Peter Parker and Spider-Man, through its knowledge of other universes.

> Speaking of biting, the screenwriters say that including Eddie Brock and his alien symbiote Venom in the film’s final battle was “definitely discussed.” The pair confirmed that Watts directed the post-credits tag on “Venom: Let There Be Carnage,” which showed Brock zapped into the MCU. But Brock was ultimately relegated to the “No Way Home” post-credits scene instead. **As for how a character who had never met any Peter Parker, let alone Spider-Man, could be pulled into the MCU by a spell specifically drawing people who had to know Peter Parker was Spider-Man? “The idea is that the symbiote has knowledge of other universes. Buried in his brain is some knowledge of that connection,” McKenna said.**
>
> <sub>[‘Spider-Man: No Way Home’ Screenwriters Explain All Those Surprises and Spoilers: ‘This Wasn’t Just Fan Service’](https://variety.com/2021/film/news/spider-man-no-way-home-spoilers-tobey-maguire-andrew-garfield-aunt-may-1235144617/)</sub>

Comment: +1 Well I think that is a pretty cracking good answer with the available evidence. Welcome @LogicDictates!